# Determine a closed form of $f(k)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^{k-n}-\int_0^1x^{k-n}dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

We observe this function of $f(k)$ through mathematical experiments  and was unable to find a closed form of it. Can anyone help us to find it?

k is an integer, where $k\ge1$

$$f(k)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^{k-n}-\int_0^1x^{k-x}dx$$

For $k=1,2,3,4,...$ the values of $f(k)=1,2,4,9,23,66,210,733,... $ are respectively.

Comment: What is the $n$ in the integrand?

Comment: An error, thank

Comment: I assume this is probably http://oeis.org/A026898

Comment: @Micah thank you. Save me a lot of time. How did you find it so quick?

Comment: OEIS has a search function. I typed in the values in the question and this was the sequence that came up...